# Xquery, use deep-equal with extra elements

Tags: xml, function, xquery

I used this function to check if a sequence do exist in another sequence  :
http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_deep-equal.html

fn:deep-equal()

The problem is that when it compares two sequences, if one sequence possess all the element of the others plus her own ones, it returns false!

I 'd like to know how it could return true if there is "at least the minimum sequence" defined by one of the function attribute.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let $len := min((count($a), count($b)))
return deep-equal(subsequence($a, 1, $len), subsequence($b, 1, $len))
```

This is assuming the length difference applies only to the top-level sequence, and not to sequences of children deeper down the tree.

Answer (score 1):

No, deep-equal checks for structural isomorphism and identity of values.  You have two options:

1 Write your own recursive function contains_subseq($a, $b) to determine whether $a contains $b as a sub-sequence (you may be able to use deep-equal on the members of the two sequences, depending on what you actually are looking for).

If the requirement is not just that all items in $a appear as items in $b, in the same order, but also that they be contiguous and begin at position 1 (i.e. if the requirement is that sequence $a appear as a prefix of sequence $b), then the solution proposed by Michael Kay will work and you don't need a function of your own.  If `(1, 3, 5)` and `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` should match, or if `(2, 3, 4)` and `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` should match, however, then you're going to need more than that.

2 If you know in advance what the required minimum sequence is, you can write a function to normalize a sequence by discarding everything else, and then use deep-equals to test whether your normalized sequence matches the minimum.